# Player's age is not edited

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

So in my program, I am statically creating and removing players. However, the editing of a players's attribute isn't working.

I have 3 action types. `ADD_PLAYER, REMOVE_PLAYER, EDIT_PLAYER`

For each one of them, I create an action generator, which contains a type and any other parameters accordingly. Here is my full code

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'; 
import uuid from 'uuid';


// ADD_PLAYER
const addPlayer = (
    {
        firstName = '',
        lastName = '',
        age = 0,
        position = ''
    } = {}) => ({
    type: 'ADD_PLAYER',
    player: {
        id: uuid(),
        firstName,
        lastName,
        age,
        position
    }
});

// REMOVE_PLAYER
const removePlayer = ( {id} = {} ) => ({
        type: 'REMOVE_PLAYER',
        id
});

// EDIT_PLAYER
const editPlayer = (id, updates) => ({
    type: 'EDIT_PLAYER',
    id,
    updates
})

const playersReduxDefaultState = [];

// The Player reducer
const playersReducer = (state = playersReduxDefaultState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_PLAYER':
            return [
                ...state,
                action.player
            ]

        case 'REMOVE_PLAYER': 
            return state.filter(({id}) => id !== action.id)

        case 'EDIT_PLAYER': 
            return state.map((player) => {
                if(player.id === action.id) {
                    return {
                        ...player,
                        ...action.updates
                    }
                } else {
                    return player
                }
            });  
        default: 
            return state;
    }
};

const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
        players: playersReducer
    })
)

store.subscribe(() => {
    console.log(store.getState())
});

store.dispatch(
    addPlayer(
        {   
            firstName: 'Theo',
            lastName: 'Tziomakas',
            age: 38,
            position: 'Striker'
        }
))

const playerOne = store.dispatch(
    addPlayer(
        {   
            firstName: 'Vasilis',
            lastName: 'Tziastoudis',
            age: 38,
            position: 'Defender'
        }
))

store.dispatch(removePlayer({ id: playerOne.player.id}));

// Edit player's one age. 
store.dispatch(editPlayer(playerOne.player.id, { age: 29 }));
```

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Theo.

Comment: In last 4 lines, you removed playerOne and then you are trying to edit playerOne. Is that intentional and correct ?

Comment: `addPlayer` action creator return player object, but dispatch doesn't return result of `addPlayer`. Am I right?

Comment: @gautamits oops. You are correct. My mistake there!

Comment: Was that issue in snippet creation ? Did it solved your problem ?

Comment: @gautamits Yes I did. I messed up the const at the end as you said.